# How to optimize this piece of PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP code that queries a MySQL database several times to get different values from it and put them into variables. I think it must be able to make this code shorter, smarter and much more efficient by looping it somehow and/or working with array's or a combination???

This is what I have:

```
$datetoday  = date('Y-m-d');
$dateyesterday  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$date2daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-2 days"));
$date3daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-3 days"));
$date4daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-4 days"));
$date5daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-5 days"));
$date6daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-6 days"));
$date7daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-7 days"));
$date8daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-8 days"));
$date9daysago   = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-9 days"));
$date10daysago  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-10 days"));
$date11daysago  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-11 days"));
$date12daysago  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-12 days"));
$date13daysago  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-13 days"));

$eventtotrack = 'Confirmation';

// Show # of Opt-Ins Today
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$datetoday'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmationstoday = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations Yesterday
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$dateyesterday'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmationsyesterday = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 2 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date2daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations2daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 3 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date3daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations3daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 4 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date4daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations4daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 5 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date5daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations5daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 6 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date6daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations6daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 7 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date7daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations7daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 8 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date8daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations8daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 9 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date9daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations9daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 10 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date10daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations10daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 11 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date11daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations11daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 12 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date12daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations12daysago = $r->num_rows;

// Show # of Confirmations 13 days ago
$q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date13daysago'";
$r = $db->query($q);
$totalconfirmations13daysago = $r->num_rows;
```

Can someone please help me, since I don't know how to shorten and optimize this in a way that all the variables are filled with the right values.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a loop! This is so basic programming stuff, it does not even matter if your case is PHP and MySQL. You must learn some basic programming concepts first! Otherwise, ask google, e.g. http://howtostartprogramming.com/PHP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use associative arrays instead of creating a new variable for each value.

```
$dates = array();
for ($daysago = 0; $daysago > -14; $daysago --) {
    $dates[$daysago] = date('Y-m-d', strototime("-".$daysago." days"));
}
$totalconfirmations = array();
foreach($dates as $key => $date){
   $q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE trackingEvent='$eventtotrack' AND trackingDate='$date'";
   $r = $db->query($q);
   $totalconfirmations[$key] = $r->num_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use as minimum query as possible

```
$datetoday  = date('Y-m-d');
$date13daysago  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-13 days"));
$eventtotrack = 'Confirmation';

$q = "SELECT DATEDIFF(`trackingDate`, '$datetoday') AS `Days_Ago`, `COUNT(`trackingEvent`) AS `num_rows`
    FROM `customers`
    WHERE `trackingEvent` = '$eventtotrack'
        AND `trackingDate` BETWEEN '$date13daysago'
        AND trackingDate = '$datetoday'
GROUP BY `Days_Ago`
ORDER BY `Days_Ago` ASC";

$r = $db->query($q);
```